# Web Api Gives 405 Method Not Allowed error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, angular

i am using Angular 2 and web api. i am using following function for API call

```
 getList(){
             let headers = new Headers();
         headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this._http
            .post('http://krtyavm1.cloudapp.net:8085/api/event/posteventtest',null, {  headers: headers })
            .map(res => res.json());
        }
```

but it gives me "405 Method Not Allowed - http://krtyavm1.cloudapp.net:8085/api/event/posteventtest" error, i am not getting exact problem,plzz help me.

Comment: Check your requests on Network Tab of browser developer tools, it must be for **OPTIONS** method. If that's the case, you will have to **enable CORS** on Web Api side.

Comment: Check windows Features to make sure WebDAV installed.

Comment: Can you add the code from your controller? Probably you forgot to add the Attributes, or you didn't enable it. It would also be helpful to see your method that bootstraps the routes.